# Firebase app check not working with iOS 16

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, ios16, firebase-app-check

It looks like for my app the firebase app check is not working with iOS16. I have configured the app attest and its been working for more than a year, it's still working with older iOS versions but not iOS 16.

This is the code that I initialise app check

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAppCheck

@main
struct appointmeparterAppApp: App {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    
    init() {
        let providerFactory = YourAppCheckProviderFactory()
        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)



         FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
}
  
class YourAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
  func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
      return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
  }
}
```

I am sure the problem is app check because if it's not enforced everything works as expected, and if I enforce it then i get permissions error. (this happens only on iOS 16)

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: @TylerV to be honest after 1-2 months of not finding anything, as I updated all dependencies to the latest versions it started working again.

Answer (score 2):

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAppCheck

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let providerFactory = ACFTAppCheckProviderFactory()
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(providerFactory)
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct ACFTApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class ACFTAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
    func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
        return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
    }
}
```

[image]

> Set the App attest env. to production. Ensure you add App Attest capability to your app target. Remove the -FIRDebugEnabled in your app scheme/run/arguments. Possibly ensure you add the debug token to your registered apps/manage tokens on FB.

Answer (score 0):

> No entitlement change to "production" required. After adding AppCheck entitlement in your applications target/signing and capabilities, you just need to add this in the AppName_App: App file.

```
    class ArmyProAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
    func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
        var isiOSAppOnMac = false
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        // App Attest is not available on simulators.
        // Use a debug provider.
        let provider = AppCheckDebugProvider(app: app)
        // Print only locally generated token to avoid a valid token leak on CI.
        print("Firebase App Check debug token: \(provider?.localDebugToken() ?? "" )")
        return provider
#else
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *), !isiOSAppOnMac {
            // Use App Attest provider on real devices.
            return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
        } else {
            return DeviceCheckProvider(app: app)
        }
#endif
    }
}


class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(ArmyProAppCheckProviderFactory())
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```